# Bootstrap Tabs reset when doing partial refresh in XPages

Tags: tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

I have an XPage that's using the [Bootstrap4Xpages project](http://bootstrap4xpages.openntf.org/).

I want to have tabs, and wasn't sure the best way to go so I did it manually using bootstrap code rather then the built in XPages tab control which historically has been "lacking".  I'm using the basic example from the documentation:
http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.1.1/docs/javascript/#tabs

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when any type of partial refresh occurs above the tabs, the current tab always moves back to the first tab.  So if someone is in a middle tab, hits an "Edit" button, it moves back to the first tab.

How can I get the Tabs to stick through a partial refresh?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the "active" class of the li-element and set it only after page load via Javascript, e.g.

```
$(".nav-tabs:first-child").addClass("active")
```

OR

make sure the tabs are not within the partial refreshed area

**UPDATE**

I fiddled around a bit and found a solution:
Have a look at the two script blocks defined here. The one at the bottom just declares and sets the default tab value. The second is placed within the refreshable area and computes the active tab after the refresh:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xc:_layoutBS3 navbarTopInverse="true"
        navbarBottomInverse="true" hideHelpArea="false" fullWidth="false">

        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:div xp:key="facetMiddle" id="refresh">
                <!-- Nav tabs -->
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">
                            <xp:label value="#{javascript:@Now()}" id="label1">
                                <xp:this.converter>
                                    <xp:convertDateTime>
                                        <xp:this.pattern><![CDATA[${javascript:"dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss"}]]></xp:this.pattern>
                                    </xp:convertDateTime>
                                </xp:this.converter>
                            </xp:label>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock2" type="text/javascript">
                    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(".nav-tabs a").on("click", function(){
        activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
}); 

if(activeTab){
    $(".nav-tabs a").each(function(){
        if($(this).attr("href") == activeTab){
            $(this).tab("show");
        }
    });
}]]></xp:this.value>
                </xp:scriptBlock>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">...</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">...</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="messages">...</div>
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="settings">...</div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <xp:link escape="true" text="Refresh" id="link1" styleClass="btn btn-default">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                        refreshMode="partial" refreshId="refresh">
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:link>
            </xp:div>

            <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1" xp:key="facetHelp"
                type="text/javascript">
                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[var activeTab = "#home";]]></xp:this.value>
            </xp:scriptBlock>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xc:_layoutBS3>
</xp:view>
```

The label that displayes the timestamp is just to prove that the partial refresh occurred.
One caveat: if you want the fade effect then the fading occurs also after every refresh. Would suggest you to not use the fade effect.

Live demo here: http://mardou.dyndns.org/bs3template.nsf/tabs.xsp

The source can be found here, too: https://github.com/zeromancer1972/Bootstrap-3-Template/blob/12a7f79cd53fe0923eb10986cfc7e581196379db/ODP/XPages/tabs.xsp

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I couldn't get that to work though. If I remove the manual active class I can't get the jQuery to set it at all.  You said "after page load" but there's no CSJS script available for that so I tried a script block.  I really don't want to move the tabs out of the partial refresh area as they contain fields and I have buttons to put all fields in all tabs in Edit or Read mode....

Comment: You have fields within the ul part of the tabs construct? Do you have to compute sth. for the tab labels?

Comment: Thank You!!!  That seems to work great.  To get it to work fully I need to put that second smaller scriptBlock at the very top of my page and the first/ bigger one at the bottom.  But it seems to be working fine.  I did have fade on..  it doesn't seem to break it having it there but it's no longer working.  So yeah, I'll just remove it.
Thanks for the help!!!!

Comment: Oliver - While this is working for me on a "normal" page - it's not working if there are parmeters on the URL for some reason.  Even the second tab in your demo behaves odd if I do something like:  http://mardou.dyndns.org/bs3template.nsf/tabs.xsp?test=first#  Any idea why additional info in the URL changes behavior?

Comment: Hmmm because of the hash you provided? What if you leave the hash alone and issue only the URL param? BTW: my solution is not to use the Bs tabs every time but using the XSP tabbed panel tabs for that. In this case the hash is used to control the tab behavior, so be careful with them. Anyway, I cannot see any issue with my sample (using Chrome, didn't test it with other browsers yet).